# Clients cannot connect after starting percona for mongodb with opensslcipherconfig

Tags: mongodb, encryption, openssl, percona

Using Percona for mongodb version 3.6.3.
Had a three node replica set running with ssl turned on and everything was happy.  Security passed down a new requirement to run with a opensslCipherConfig.  So I shutdown and restarted mongodb with --setParameter opensslCipherConfig.

Clients are now unable to connect.

[thread1] Error: socket exception [CLOSED]

Nothing in the mongo logs to help.

Start mongo from command line --- 
mongod -f /etc/mongod.conf  --replSet repl_set1  --setParameter opensslCipherConfig="ECDHE-RSA-AES256-SHA384:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES256-SHA384"

connect to mongo from command line ---
 mongo mongodb:27017/admin --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile /mongodb.pem --verbose

error --
Percona Server for MongoDB shell version v3.6.3-1.1
connecting to: mongodb://mongodb:27017/admin

2019-03-01T14:55:54.164+0000 D NETWORK  [thread1] creating new connection to:mongodb:27017

2019-03-01T14:55:54.166+0000 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CLOSED] : connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:251:13
@(connect):1:6

2019-03-01T14:55:54.166+0000 D -        [thread1] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/shell/shell_utils.cpp 270

2019-03-01T14:55:54.166+0000 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 3742635 limit: 0

2019-03-01T14:55:54.167+0000 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 313635 limit: 0

2019-03-01T14:55:54.167+0000 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC prologue heap stats -  total: 204795 limit: 0

2019-03-01T14:55:54.167+0000 I QUERY    [thread1] MozJS GC epilogue heap stats -  total: 11859 limit: 0

2019-03-01T14:55:54.167+0000 D -        [main] User Assertion: 12513:connect failed src/mongo/scripting/mozjs/proxyscope.cpp 300

Comment: Elaborate more about it. Show us your code.

Comment: Please show us the SSL-related part of your /etc/mongod.conf. Also, there should be some error info in the mongod log file. You can also try to increase log verbosity if there is nothing.

Answer (score 0):

There is a bug. I opened a ticket with Percona. [https://jira.percona.com/browse/PSMDB-412] . In the Percona Jira ticket, percona responded ” Related upstream tickets: SERVER-36616, SERVER-38141”.

Those are mongoDB Jira Tickets 
[https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-36616] – fixed mongo version 4.1.5
[https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-38141] – fixed mongo version 4.1.6

The latest available MongoDB versions is 4.0.10… upcoming releases 4.1.13 and 4.2.0-rc2 are both available for development release.